# Работа с консолью на винде

Tags: cmd, hyper-v

Смотрю видеоуроки одного челика, он работает на Маке.
Он часто передает при запуске другой порт или окружение типа:
NODE_ENV=production yarn start
PORT = 5555 yarn start

У него все работает, но на винде вылезает 
"NODE_ENV" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
Мб кто то знает как исправить?

Comment: `set NODE_ENV=production` отдельной командой и только потом yarn?

Comment: @andreymal  ноу, вместе все, одной командой и без сет

Comment: Но зачем, когда можно раздельными командами и с сет?)

Comment: @andreymal так тоже не работает, запускает по старому порту и тд